# retry HTTP request without using factory

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to retry a http call when it rejected, without using `factory`?
I thought of making a custom service and send it the http method, url and callbacks functions. but I would like to know if there is better way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `$http` call in a function and call that function from within the resulting promise's error callback:

```
function makeHttpRequest(){

  $http.post("your-url-goes-here")
       .then(successCallback, errorCallback);

  function successCallback(obj){
    // do something...
  } 

  function errorCallback(err){
    makeHttpRequest();
  }
}
```

There is obviously huge potential for an infinite loop using this approach and you would be wise to restrict the number of retry attempts.